# size of a Matplotlib figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

Am trying to make my figure fit the window in terms of its width, and have experimented on the ones have commented out(Line 1, 3, and 4) in the part of the full code below and the attached screenshot is the way it is now. Anyone to help, please.[image: Figure width size]

```
# fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (40, 2), dpi = 80, constrained_layout = True)
#fig = plt.gcf()
#fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_title("Electrocadiogram")
ax.set_xlabel("Time(Sec)")
ax.set_ylabel("Voltage(mV)")
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#666666', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=plotting_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 600, height = 420)
```

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: @Karina Python 3.9.7 and Matplotlib 3.4.3 my apologies for not stating.

Comment: I have the same version and it works for me though.. did you try ``fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (40, 2), constrained_layout=True)``?

Comment: @Karina I have tried that still no change.

Comment: @Karina thank you for your response really appreciate and GOD bless you.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out, the canvas was restricting the size of the figure on which it was embedded, so I played with the canvas width and it has worked.

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 1170, height = 420)
```

[image: size of a matplotlib figure]